# Manual Provisioning on Xamarin IOS development provisioning profile. Which config did it choose?

Tags: xamarin.forms, provisioning-profile, code-signing-certificate

When I right click on the Xamarin Forms iOS project in VS2017 and choose properties -> iOS Bundle signing, the only  way I can get my app to deploy is to choose:

1) "Manual Provisioning" in the Bundle Signing Scheme.
2) "Developer (Automatic)" in the Signing Identity.
3) "Automatic" in the Provisioning Profile section.
4) I then add Entitlements file.

Is there any way of working out what was chosen on my behalf in steps 2 and 3?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> What was chosen on your behalf in steps 2 and 3?

**Signing Identity** 
It will  automatically choose the Developer teams and  generate an AppID for you .Which named as VS and the `Bundle Identifier` .Such as `VS com yourcompanyname appname`

[image]

Before you start the automatic signing process, you should ensure that you have an Apple ID added in Visual Studio.As described in the [Apple Account Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/apple-account-management?tabs=windows) guide.

**Provisioning Profile** It will generate a Provisioning Profile for you .

[image]

Provisioning is the process of preparing and configuring an app to launch on devices and to use app services. Development Provisioning Profiles holds the device identifiers ( UUID ) that is eligible to run your app. Distribution Provisioning Profiles can include App Store profiles, that lets you distribute your app to the App Store and Ad-hoc profiles are good for distributing to your testers.

For more details and differences between `Automatic Provisioning` and `Manual Provisionin` you can refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/automatic-provisioning?tabs=windows).

Comment: That's fab @Lucas Zhang - MSFT thanks but I already have a fully functioning app having gone through all the steps above. I have three App IDs in my member area of apple.developer. I think I was too vague in my question, what I want to know is where are these variables output by VS in the build process? I want to see what the value of the APP ID is

Comment: I give up. I really give up.

Comment: Didn't my answer help you？

Comment: How do you get to this screen? I can't find it